# LinqToExcel Duplicate Column Names

Tags: c#, excel, linq-to-excel

I have a machine generated excel file that has a few columns with the same name. e.g.:

```
  A       B          C       D
Group 1           Group 2
Period | Name     Period | Name
```

And i got a DTO like this:

```
[ExcelColumn("Period")]
public string FirstPeriod { get; set; }
[ExcelColumn("Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[ExcelColumn("Period")]
public string SecondPeriod { get; set; }
[ExcelColumn("Name")]
public string SecondName { get; set; }
```

I use the following command to read the lines:

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(filePath);
excel.WorksheetRange<T>(beginCell, endColl + linesCount.ToString(), sheetIndex);
```

It reads the file just fine, but when i check the content of my DTO i saw that all the 'Second' properties have the same values of the 'First' ones.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047800/referencing-columns-in-linqtoexcel-using-ordinal-position) was the closest thing that i found in my searches and i think the problem could be solved with something like this:

```
excel.AddMapping<MyDto>(x => x.FirstPeriod, "A");
excel.AddMapping<MyDto>(x => x.FirstName, "B");
excel.AddMapping<MyDto>(x => x.SecondPeriod, "C");
excel.AddMapping<MyDto>(x => x.SecondName, "D");
```

But i don't know how to get the excel column letters...

Obs: I got a few more code behind this but i don't think its relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you're having is not possible to solve today with LinqToExcel because it wraps the OleDb functions and then they map properties based on columns names, so you lose the OleDb options like "FN" for specify columns (like "F1" for "A").

There's a issue on LinqToExcel github repo about this. https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel/issues/85

I recommend you to change the name of the columns to not duplicates names (e.g. Period1, Name1, Period2, Name2) if it's not possible to change because its machine generated, try change the header names in runtime.

Another option is to make more than one query in excel file, with ranges splitted your groups and then merging the results later.

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(filePath);
var group1 = excel.WorksheetRange<T>(A1, B + rowCount);
var group2 = excel.WorksheetRange<T>(C1, D + rowCount);
```

*Edit: I'll work on a feature to try solve this problem in a elegant manner, so maybe in future you have a more flexible option to map columns and properties (if they accept my Pull Request)*